# How I can Slide down other component using antd in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm new to react and I have a scenario where I'm using Drawer component of antd, and it's working fine, but by default it open a popup (slide from top) of the page, but here my requirement is instead of open pop-up I want to open as normal component and it have toggle button, if it off then it get slide up(hide) and if toggle is on then it slide down, and rest of component of the page also slide down to make space for it.

Please help me how can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: I think that is how it works. They have a button which onclick opens the drawer : https://ant.design/components/drawer/ You set state to true for open and false for close

Comment: Drawer won't work for my scenario then can you tell me what else I can use? They are opening a popup top of the page but my requirement is to slide it down with all existing component.

Comment: You want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r10kcqeh/1/) ?

Comment: not exactly.. there are more component under the show results and that need to be slide down accordingly.

Comment: @MahendraGarg Drawer is mounted outside the root node and to achieve your goal, using antd drawer will be a complicated task. I worked on your requirements but without using antd drawer (but used the same code as antd drawer) Requirement:When drawer is toggled, it open from top and slide down all the content. May be it's not look like what you want, but if you want it, i can post the code as an answer.

Comment: @NoumanRafique you can post your answer too, It can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly this is what I want, but it is without Drawer [Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/collapsibleaccordination-component-5u2f7?from-embed=&file=/assets/index.css), It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Portal = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div className='ant-drawer ant-drawer-top ant-drawer-open' style={{ position: 'static' }}>
            {visible && (
                <>
                    <div className='ant-drawer-content-wrapper' style={{ height: '378px', position: 'initial' }}>
                        <div className='ant-drawer-content'>
                            <div className='ant-drawer-wrapper-body'>
                                <div className='ant-drawer-header ant-drawer-header-close-only'>
                                    <div className='ant-drawer-header-title'>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            aria-label='Close'
                                            className='ant-drawer-close'
                                            onClick={() => setVisible(false)}
                                        >
                                            <span role='img' aria-label='close' className='anticon anticon-close'>
                                                <svg
                                                    viewBox='64 64 896 896'
                                                    focusable='false'
                                                    data-icon='close'
                                                    width='1em'
                                                    height='1em'
                                                    fill='currentColor'
                                                    aria-hidden='true'
                                                >
                                                    <path d='M563.8 512l262.5-312.9c4.4-5.2.7-13.1-6.1-13.1h-79.8c-4.7 0-9.2 2.1-12.3 5.7L511.6 449.8 295.1 191.7c-3-3.6-7.5-5.7-12.3-5.7H203c-6.8 0-10.5 7.9-6.1 13.1L459.4 512 196.9 824.9A7.95 7.95 0 00203 838h79.8c4.7 0 9.2-2.1 12.3-5.7l216.5-258.1 216.5 258.1c3 3.6 7.5 5.7 12.3 5.7h79.8c6.8 0 10.5-7.9 6.1-13.1L563.8 512z' />
                                                </svg>
                                            </span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className='ant-drawer-body' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
            <Button type='primary' onClick={() => setVisible((prev) => !prev)}>
                {visible ? 'Close' : 'Open'} Drawer
            </Button>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};

function App() {
    return (
        <Portal>
            {Array.from({ length: 20 }).map((_, index) => (
                <h1 key={index}>Heading {index + 1}</h1>
            ))}
        </Portal>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

customising the antd drawer will get complex i guess.

you can write your custom drawer by adding height auto or in px when drawer is visible and 0px when drawer is hidden

```
export function CustomDrawer() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{
          height: visible ? "200px" : "0px",
          transition: "2s",
          overflow: "hidden",
        }}
      >
        <p>drawer body</p>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setVisible(!visible);
        }}
      >
        click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```